# Is it possible in a JavaEE6 application server to obtain a reference to the "instanciator" component

Tags: jakarta-ee, inversion-of-control

In JavaEE6, we can make good use of IoC through various annotations (`@EJB`, `@Resource`, ...).

But, is it possible to obtain an instance of the server component used to instanciate those objects ? What for ? Well, in some case, i want to be able to instanciate objects (of random classes) that may contain `@EJB` and other similar references. To ease my job, it would be great if I could use the component used by the server to instanciate my application, as I wouldn't have to configure myself usable classpath and other such elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To instanciate objects in CDI, one should not try to find instanciator object (named [`BeanManager`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html)), but rather access to already defined instances, which are [`Instance`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) objects. As an example, to access the generic instance, one can simply define an `instance` variable this way :

```
 @Inject private Instance<?> instance;
```

Then use it anywhere in the code to instanciate a random class :

```
MyEJB ejb = instance.select(MyEJB.class).get();
```